# Trying to find a 1980's cartoon about cowboys and aliens

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I'm trying to remember a cartoon from the 1980s involving a cowboy and aliens.   (No, it has nothing to do with the film Cowboy & Aliens.)  There was a horse who could stand on its hind legs like a human.  I'm sorry for the lack of details.

Comment: Good thing you mentioned the horse, otherwise I'd have suggested [Saber Rider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saber_Rider_and_the_Star_Sheriffs) (Colt Willcox is kind of a Cowboy)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is ***BraveStarr***, which aired from 1987 to 1988 and which was produced by Filmation Studios.  The cowboy in question was **Marshal BraveStarr**.  It took place on a distant planet called **New Texas**.  There were plenty of alien species around.

What gave it away for me was the horse — it's good you mentioned that detail.  BraveStarr's horse was named **Thirty/Thirty**, and he could stand and walk on his hind legs:

[image]

Comment: Hot diggity, you're fast!

Comment: @WadCheber : Fastest gun in the west --- particularly apt on this one. ;-)  I'm always on the watch for story identification questions.  I either recognize them instantly or not at all.  (What gave this one away was the walking horse!)

Comment: Strength of the bear...bear...bear!

Comment: @WadCheber that last comment is more appropriate for politics.se...

Comment: @jwenting - Meh.

Comment: Eyes of the Hawk, Ears of the Wolf, Strength of the Bear.

Comment: @jwenting nah, it's still fun.

Comment: Firefly, the animated series?

Comment: Does it switch back and forth between four-legged stance and two?  Is this an anthropomorphic horse, a cyborg horse or what?

Comment: @ThePopMachine : Thirty/Thirty actually is a cyborg horse and can switch back and forth between stances at will!

Comment: Why was he called Thirty/Thirty?

Comment: @maguirenumber6, probably for the rifle of the same name, the [Winchester .30-30](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.30-30_Winchester)

Comment: @Hellion Ah I see. Makes sense. Thanks :-)

Comment: Wasn't there also speed of the puma?